# How to pass IN or NOT IN clause as variable to postgresql query using python

Tags: python, postgresql, variables, in-clause

How to pass `IN` OR `NOT IN` clause as variable to a query?

When I pass the variable in the query bellow I get :

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name 'IN' ('product', 'category')`

which triger an error for the presence of quotes `'IN'`

```
query_clause = 'IN' 
##query_clause could equal 'NOT IN'

cur = my_connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name %s ('product', 'category')", (query_clause,))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's expected.  Use a boolean parameter instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
  WHERE (column_name IN ('product', 'category')) = %s
```

You can then pass true or false into the parameter.

Comment: oh thats a great solution to sanitize user input for this

Comment: Thank you Dietrich! That is a VERY cleaver solution and work around!! it did work like charm :)

Answer (score 2):

you cant use a sql format string for that ... just a normal format string

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name %s ('product', 'category')"%(query_clause,))
```

its worth noting this assumes `query_clause` is trusted input ... (it will not sanitize against injection if this is not trusted input)

Comment: Thank you Joran! you are right, its gonna be open to sql injection if we use `%s`.

Comment: an ORM is usually the real solution ;)